# sequelize multiple primary keys

Tags: foreign-keys, sequelize.js

I have some problem with Sequelize having multiple primary keys; therefore the multiple foreign keys with multiple hasMany on same table.

Suppose I have User

```
const User = sequelize.define('User', {
    id: { type: DataTypes.STRING(6), field: 'ID', primaryKey : true }
)
associate: function(models) {
        User.hasMany(models.Post, { foreignKey: 'userId' });
}
```

and I have Post under User

```
const Post = sequelize.define('Post', {
    id: { type: DataTypes.STRING(6), field: 'ID', primaryKey: true }, // primary key
    userId: { type: DataTypes.STRING(6), field: 'USER_ID', primaryKey: true },           // primary key
)
associate: (models) => {
        Post.belongsTo(models.User, { foreignKey: 'userId' });
        Post.hasMany(models.PostImage, { onDelete: 'CASCADE', foreignKey: 'postId' });// { key1: 'id', key2: 'userId'}
        Post.hasMany(models.PostImage, { onDelete: 'CASCADE', foreignKey: 'userId' });// { key1: 'id', key2: 'userId'}
}
```

and Post Images under Post

```
const PostImage = sequelize.define('PostImage', {
    postId: { type: DataTypes.STRING(6), field: 'POST_ID', primaryKey: true },
    userId: { type: DataTypes.STRING(6), field: 'USER_ID', primaryKey: true }
)
associate: (models) => {
        PostImage.belongsTo(models.Post, { foreignKey: 'postId' });
        PostImage.belongsTo(models.Post, { foreignKey: 'userId' });
}
```

Now it seems like two primary keys with two foreign keys are not working for 'include' method for using findOne or findAll.

```
Post.findAll({
      attributes: ['id', 'userId', 'content', 'modifyDate', 'registerDate'],
      where: {...},
      include: [{
        model: models.PostImages,
      }
)
```

It seems only one primary key with one foreign key is linked to each other for table Post and Post Image. So If I remove the relation

```
Post.hasMany(models.PostImage, { onDelete: 'CASCADE', foreignKey: 'userId' });// { key1: 'id', key2: 'userId'}
```

from Post to make only one foreign key with Post Image, then it would work as I expected. But it causes the problem because it only considers Post ID of Post Image, not users, so that it brings the other user's post images as well.

How can I use the multiple primary keys with multiple foreign keys in sequelize?